# Laravel Sanctum can be use Multiauth guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm testing with laravel sanctum but here some issues..
I'm creating Admin guard.

[image]

When I change the middleware to auth:sanctum_admin.. it should be only can access by admin but here I can access with normal user account with web guard. I don't know why?...I used passport with multiauth package.it's fine. but here in sanctum can't be separate User Table and Admin.

Answer (score 12):

You can, also use multiple guards in sanctum. To achieve this, follow these steps -

1. Create your own guard as required. (In `config/auth.php`)

```php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ]
    ],
```

2. Set providers. (In `config/auth.php`)

```php
'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\User::class,
       ],

       'admins' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Admin::class,
       ],
   ],
```

3. Use this guard when you authenticate a user. (In route file)

   ```php
   if(auth()->guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password')))
   {
       return auth()->guard('admin')->user();
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for the contribution. Can I ask that you copy the code from the images and place them into the markdown? We try to avoid screenshots of code on Stack Overflow because they're hard for other users to copy and paste from and they don't show up in search results (e.g., if someone is searching by keywords in them).

Comment: Driver should be 'sanctum' in auth config.

Answer (score 8):

@Abhishek Mitra

and for authorizatioin using Laravel Sanctum in case of `Multiple Auth Guard`, we can use middleware as such

```
Route::middleware(['auth:guard_name'])->get('/user', function(){
    return auth()->guard('guard_name')->user();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**config/auth.php**

driver is **sanctum**

```
'guards' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'partners' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'partners',
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

        ],
```

provider:

```
providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'partners' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Partner::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

model:

must be add **Authenticatable**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Middleware:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->get('/user', function(){
   
}
```

Guard:

```
auth()->guard('admin')->user();
```

**Unauthenticated user message:**

In app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

function:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
       return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);

}
```

or

custom guard and custom redirect

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    $class = get_class($exception);

    switch($class) {
        case 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException':
            $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
            switch ($guard) {
                case 'admin':
                    $login = 'admin.login';
                    break;
                default:
                    $login = 'login';
                    break;
            }

            return redirect()->route($login);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: `'driver' => 'sanctum'` Guard Works for me. Thanks  @ßãlãjî

Answer (score 1):

1. you must add your custom guard in **config/auth.php**.

'guards' => [

```
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'custom-guard' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'custom-provider',
    ]
],
```

be careful, the **driver** in custom guard must be **session**.
and set provider as:

```
'providers' => [
   'users' => [
       'driver' => 'eloquent',
       'model' => App\User::class,
   ],

   'custom-provider' => [
       'driver' => 'eloquent',
       'model' => App\CustomProvider::class,
   ],
```

],
the App\CustomProvider::class must be the model.
after that can easily use the guard in auth.

```
auth('custom-guard')->user()
```

Answer (score 1):

In config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
    ...

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

(Tested in Laravel 9.x)

Answer (score 1):

Defining **API sanctum guards** using the `sanctum` driver

```
'guards' => [
        // Web Guards
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        //API Sanctum Guards
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'vendor-api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],
    ],
```

Defining **Providers**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
    'vendors' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Vendor::class,
    ],
],
```

Generating **Token**

```
$user = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
$token = $user->createToken(uniqid());
return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];


$user = Vendor::where('email', $request->email)->first();
$token = $user->createToken(uniqid());
return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
```

**Protecting Routes** using `sanctum guard`

```
Route::middleware('auth:admin-api')->get('/admin', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:vendor-api')->get('/vendor', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: `member' => [ 'driver' => 'sanctum', 'provider' => 'members' ],`

it throw error 
{
    "message": "Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '256' frames",

}

`Route::middleware('auth:member')->get('/manage-profile', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});`

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue and solved it by following -

1. In `auth.php` add an extra Guard - `front`

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'front' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Vanguard\User::class,
        ],

        'members' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => Vanguard\Member::class,
        ],
    ],
```

2. Log in as a Default User or Member

```
/** Default Guard**/
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $credentials['username'], 'password' => $credentials['password']], $request->get('remember'))) {
}
/** Front Guard **/
if (Auth::guard('front')->attempt(['username' => $credentials['username'], 'password' => $credentials['password']], $request->get('remember'))) {
}
```

3. Finally add the Guard in `sanctum.php`

```
'guard' => ['front','web']
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the default guard should be like this:

```
'defaults'{
    'guard' : "sanctum_admin",
    'passwords': 'admins',
}
```

Or

```
'defaults'{
    'guard' : 'web',
    'passwords' : 'users',
}
```