# Laravel - Is logout route public

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, logout, laravel-sanctum

I want to use laravel\sanctum with SPA Authentication, where Laravel is backend api and Vue is frontend SPA. I do all manual says about it, but I faced with problem:
when my logout route in **api.php**

```
Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])
```

is under **middleware('auth:sanctum')** I couldn't logout the user because of error:

```
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.
```

where logout function is:

```
Auth::logout();
```

But when I remove **middleware('auth:sanctum')** - logout function works great and user log out.
The question is: *Should the logout route be protected or not*?

Addition: for those, who want to said: use Auth::logout('web') - it doesn't work, because the user remains logged in.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly use guard.
Change web with your custom guard:

```
Auth::guard('web')->logout();
```

Comment: When I use this if doesn't work, use is still loging ! Or explain how should i use custom (not "web") guard

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701991/3621350

Comment: I don't understand why i have to use custom guard. Sanctum auth should protect logout route or not?

Comment: @MaximStogniy You shouldn't use custom guard. There will be no security issue if you not protect logout route